# How do I raise an Exception when execution exceeds 60 seconds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am evaluating some code and, at times, see that the Ruby code I am executing runs over a 60 second mark.

Does anyone have an example of raising an exception based on a time limit?

Answer (score 5):

```
require "timeout"
Timeout.timeout(60) do
   <your code here>
end
```

This will raise a `Timeout::Error` exception. You can also pass in your custom exception to the timeout:

```
Timeout.timeout(60, <CustomException>)
```

Refer to the [Timeout](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html) documentation for more information.

Comment: I changed your link because API doc is significantly out of date. Ruby docs are available online at http://ruby-doc.org/ and are the preferred site. http://rdoc.info/github is also very good.